# Add lines to the `BODY` element of an auto-generated JUnit 5 test method in IntelliJ

Tags: templates, intellij-idea, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

When using the IntelliJ menu item `Code` > `Generate…` > `Test` to generate a JUnit 5 test class, the result is controlled by the template defined in `Preferences`/`Settings` > `Editor` > `File and Code Templates` > `Code` (tab) > `JUnit5 Test Method` (list item). The contents of that item look like this:

```
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void ${NAME}() {
  ${BODY}
}
```

When run, it produces content like this:

```
@Test
void parse () {
}
```

How can I change that template to produce this:

```
@Test
@DisplayName ( "NameGoesHere" )
void parse () {
    // ------|  Arrange  |--------------------------

    // ------|  Act  |------------------------------

    // ------|  Assert  |---------------------------

}
```

I do not know what to do with that variable named `BODY` which is where I want to add this hard-coded lines of comments and blanks.

Comment: You could add needed code into the template before or after BODY. BODY is a variable that is configured if you run "Code | Generate | Test Method". First method name is pre-selected and after pressing "Enter" caret is moved to the next variable (BODY in this case)